# Interacting with 3D objects in Python 3?

Tags: python, 3d, python-3.x

I am currently in the planing stage of building an interactive periodic table of the elements program in python 3. It won't be a super advanced program, since I am only a beginner in python 3 (4-5 months of self-training).

Basically, when you click on an element of the periodic table, you will look at its properties in more detail and would have a dynamic 3D view of the an animated atom (with the electrons circling around it) which I would create in Blender. [Here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/397277/periodic_table.png) is a simple mockup I just made for people who are visual (lots of stuff missing here, but it's only the basic shell).

Ok, so my question is: How can I interact with 3D objects in Python 3? I have searched, and have found that PyGame can handle this, but it seems it's not the best to handle 3D graphics, and I am not sure if PyGame is ideal for this kind of program. Of course, there is vpython, but it doesn't work with Python 3. So how can I manage to do this?

Please keep in mind that I am a beginner, so any resources you think can help me would be of great appreciation!

Thanks to all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest could be to use images and videos.

But if you want to manipulate 3D, there are [PyOpenGL](http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/) and [VPython](http://vpython.org/).

Comment: Vpython is compatible with Python 3.x?

Comment: Is it possible to embed a vpython application into, let's say a PyQT application?

Comment: You can find the code for Win32 [here](http://blog.csdn.net/koening/article/details/6182141) but for PyQt, I  found nothing.
VPython is very simple to use, but I think PyOpenGL is more durable.

Comment: Is there a good book on PyOpenGL I should consider? Or any book on openGL should work?

Comment: There are the [NeHe tutorials](http://nehe.gamedev.net/) (look at the right sidebar)

Answer (score 0):

PyOpenGL provides low level interface to display 3D objects.
PyOpenGL can be used with PyQt or PyGame to have a 3D display within a 2D GUI.

Edit: there is also a build of vpython for 32bit python 3.1 on windows

Answer (score 0):

[Glass Engine](https://pypi.org/project/glass-engine/) can help you to add interactive 3D viewport in your PyQt program. For example, use [Glass Engine](https://pypi.org/project/glass-engine/) to draw a Helium atom：

```py
from glass_engine import *
from glass_engine.Geometries import *
from PyQt6.QtCore import QTimer

import math

scene, camera, light = ModelView()
light.generate_shadows = False

# calculate nucleon positions
sqrt_6 = math.sqrt(6)
sqrt_2 = math.sqrt(2)
sqrt_3 = math.sqrt(3)
nucleon_positions = \
[
    0.1*glm.normalize(glm.vec3( 2/3*sqrt_2, 0, -1/3)), # 0
    0.1*glm.normalize(glm.vec3( -sqrt_2/3, sqrt_6/3, -1/3)), # 1
    0.1*glm.normalize(glm.vec3( -sqrt_2/3,   -sqrt_6/3, -1/3)), # 2
    0.1*glm.normalize(glm.vec3( 0,    0,   1)), # 3
]

# assemble He atom
He_atom = SceneNode()

# add two protons
proton1 = Sphere(radius=0.1, color=10*glm.vec3( 0.77, 0.38, 0 ))
proton1.material.shading_model = None
proton1.position = nucleon_positions[0]
He_atom.add_child(proton1)

proton2 = Sphere(radius=0.1, color=10*glm.vec3( 0.77, 0.38, 0 ))
proton2.material.shading_model = None
proton2.position = nucleon_positions[1]
He_atom.add_child(proton2)

# add two neutrons
neutron1 = Sphere(radius=0.1, color=glm.vec3( 0.71, 0.77, 0.89 ))
neutron1.position = nucleon_positions[2]
He_atom.add_child(neutron1)

neutron2 = Sphere(radius=0.1, color=glm.vec3( 0.71, 0.77, 0.89 ))
neutron2.position = nucleon_positions[3]
He_atom.add_child(neutron2)

# add two electrons
electron = Sphere(radius=0.05, color=10*glm.vec3(0.4, 0.7, 0.7))
electron.material.shading_model = None
electron.position.x = 1

electron_orbit = Circle(radius=1, color=10*glm.vec3(0.4, 0.7, 0.7), line_width=1)
electron_orbit.material.shading_model = None

electron1_base_node = SceneNode()
electron1_base_node.roll = -45
electron1_base_node.add_child(electron_orbit)
electron1_node = SceneNode()
electron1_base_node.add_child(electron1_node)
electron1_node.add_child(electron)
He_atom.add_child(electron1_base_node)

electron2_base_node = SceneNode()
electron2_base_node.roll = -135
electron2_base_node.add_child(electron_orbit)
electron2_node = SceneNode()
electron2_base_node.add_child(electron2_node)
electron2_node.add_child(electron)
He_atom.add_child(electron2_base_node)

scene.add(He_atom)

def electron_rotate():
    electron1_node.yaw += 2
    electron2_node.yaw -= 2
    camera.screen.update()

timer = QTimer()
timer.timeout.connect(electron_rotate)
timer.start(20)

camera.screen.bloom = True
camera.screen.FXAA = True
camera.screen.show()
```

Then you can get this result: [He atom animation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fjG4U.gif).

And in the code, `camera.screen` is just a PyQt's QWidget, you can layout it anywhere in your program.

See full document of Glass Engine at [https://glass-engine-doc.readthedocs.io/zh/latest](https://glass-engine-doc.readthedocs.io/zh/latest/index.html)